# Question on Partial derivatives in inverse function changing from coordinate systems

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensors, rotations, chain-rule, jacobian

I would like to ask a question about partial derivatives in the context of Rotations of coordinate systems. Say we have a coordinate system (unprimed) and its rotated version  (primed).  If the relation between the coordinates is linear (Does it have to be? Please, explain), how could I prove the following equation:

$${\frac{\partial x'_i}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x'_i}}$$

I am not sure I have to use the chain rule or I could come up with some simple explanation (basic). But I keep moving in circles. Please if someone could shed some light into this I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks to me if the relation is only linear then the equation is not necessarily true, for instance simply consider one coordinate system is just scaling $2$ times the other then one derivative is $1\over 2$ and the other is $2$. The necessary condition seems to me that one coordinate system must be the translation/rotation(not too sure about rotation yet) of the other with no scaling.

Comment: @cr001 What gets me is that after several hours, I could at best get the relation $\frac{\partial{x'_{i}}}{\partial{x_{j}}}=\frac{\partial{x_{i}}}{\partial{x'_{j}}}$, but even so, I am not completely sure it is the right relationship. If the context is rotation without scaling I still do not see how the textbook came to this result.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your functions $\ f\ $ and $\ g\ $ are intended to be.  If $\ f\ $ is a transformation from polar to Cartesian coordinates, for example, it will be a $2$-dimensional vector-valued function of $2$ variables. The equations relating the Cartesian coordinates, $\ x_1', x_2'\ $ to the polar coordinates $\ x_1, x_2$ are $x_1' = f_1(x_1,x_2) = x_1 \cos(x_2)\ $, $\ x_2'=f_2(x_1, x_2)= x_1\sin(x_2)\ $, and it makes no sense to write $\ f(x_i) = x_i'\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: Thank you very much for your comment. It actually made me realize I was asking the wrong question, or my approach was off.

Comment: @cr001: Thank you very much for your comment. It actually made me realize I was asking the wrong question, or my approach was off.